# excel 365 macro that previously worked fine is now saving tabs as CSV with 9999 rows even if the rows are empty, why would it do that?

Tags: vba, csv, microsoft-excel-365

update: I also just tried to do a plain old 'save as' on my tab manually and that also results in the comma rows appearing up to 9999.

When the spreadsheet is open I see no data in the rows that end up being nothing but commas. When I open the CSV, the rows at the bottom up to 9999 are just 16 commas (the same number of commas for the rows that actually do have data). Below is the VB code but it hasn't changed so not sure why this would suddenly be an issue.

```
    For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not xWs.Name Like "_*" Then
            xWs.Copy
            Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
            sFolderPath = jobsFolderPath & xWs.Name & "\"
            MkDir sFolderPath
            xcsvFile = sFolderPath & "query.csv"
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, _
            FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
            Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End If
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

update: the tab being saved to CSV was created with a macro and that macro had logic for setting font color via a cell range. Apparently this color assignment is the the root cause of why the empty rows were believed to be in use. Without asking the person who made the macro, I don't know how you could possibly notice a stand alone tab's font/colors were manipulated via a macro.

[Link to thread that highlights a macro that deletes unused rows. This works but I shouldn't have to do this...](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-is-saving-blank-rows-causing-extremely-large/113ec8cd-d76d-4ebd-a1df-3253b12bda97)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).